# Does HTML standard define how incorrectly nested tags are converted to the DOM tree?

Tags: html

I would like to know whether the HTML standard defines how overlapping tags are split into the DOM tree representation.

For example:

```
<a href="aaa">
    abcd
    <div style="font-style:italic;">
        efgh
    </a>
    ijkl
</div>
```

Here, `<a>` and `<div>` tags overlap, but inspecting the page in Chrome I see this:

```
<a href="aaa">
    abcd
</a>
<div style="font-style:italic;">
    <a href="aaa">
        efgh
    </a>
    ijkl
</div>
```

Is this behavior defined in the standard or is it browser specific?

Comment: "overlapping" → *incorrectly nested*

Comment: Some of these cases are described in [section 8.2.8 of W3C HTML5](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#an-introduction-to-error-handling-and-strange-cases-in-the-parser), but that section is informative.

Comment: Apart from *how* the fault is resolved, it is always resolved. Chrome, as any browser, tries to read the HTML source and interpret it as good as possible. Errors are corrected or discarded and what remains is an in-memory object representation (the DOM, for Document Object Model) of the document. When you inspect an element, Chrome translates that object back to HTML for you, so the HTML you see on inspection is always correct for that reason.

Comment: @deceze - thanks, fixed.

Comment: @BoltClock - Thanks! That is what I was looking for. Can you post that as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Browsers usually have feature which completes non-closed and non-opened tags unless they're self-closing like `<input />`.
You already have an answer in and example in your question.
I don't know where it's described so cannot post you reference link.
But this is how it works.

Comment: You could use the links from BoltClock's comment.

Comment: @GolezTrol ok, thanks. That's because i havent seent this comment at the moment of writing